# Finding the Anagrams of a word from a list- codewars question

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, anagram

I am pretty new to programming and I was solving a problem on code wars which is as follows:

Question:
Write a function that will find all the anagrams of a word from a list. You will be given two inputs a word and an array with words. You should return an array of all the anagrams or an empty array if there are none.
This is my code

```
function anagrams(word, words) {
 let word_Array = word.split('').sort()
 let total = []
 for (x = 0; x<words.length; x++) {
    if(words[x].split('').sort() === word_Array) {
   total.push(words[x])
 } return total 
}
}
```

The result should look something like this
`anagrams('abba', ['aabb', 'abcd', 'bbaa', 'dada']) => ['aabb', 'bbaa']`

I keep getting an empty array when I run my code. Please can someone tell me the error in my code. Thank you

Comment: you return total inside the loop, therefore, the loop won't run more than once - and if `if(words[x].split('').sort() === word_Array)` is false in that one time the loop runs, then total will be an empty array

Comment: Thank you! How would you reccommend I fix this?

Comment: return outside the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the following snippet.

```js
const sort = (word) => word.split('').sort().join('');

function anagrams(word, words) {
  let token = sort(word);
  let total = []

  for (let x = 0; x < words.length; x++) {
    if (sort(words[x]) === token) {
      total.push(words[x])
    }    
  }
  
  return total
}

console.log(anagrams('abba', ['aabb', 'abcd', 'bbaa', 'dada']));
```

You are on the right track but missed a few details.

1. As others have mentioned you cant just compare discrete arrays with `===`. The best you can do is an element wise compare. You dont really need to this if you compare normal value types such as `numbers`, `strings`, `bools`, ect. If you join the sorted string back its much easier to compare using built in operators such as `===`.
2. Your control logic is wrong. Notice how you are returning straight from the loop? It means that at most you would ever get one results since the loop cant iterative over the full loop condition.
3. You should always qualify your variable declarations with `let/const`. This was missing in the for loop and would declare `x` as a global.

#### Improvements

You could replace the `for` loop with a [for of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and not have to worry about indexing.

```
for (let w of words) {
  console.log(w); // we no longer have to worry about words[i].
}
```

Even better you could replace the entire `for` and `array.push` logic with a simple [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const sort = (word) => word.split('').sort().join('');

function anagrams(word, words) {
  let token = sort(word);
  
  return words.filter((w) => sort(w) === token);
}

console.log(anagrams('abba', ['aabb', 'abcd', 'bbaa', 'dada']));
```

Comment: Omg this is so awesome! Thank you so much for the explanation, you really went into detail with it and I very much appreciate that. Thank you so much! God bless you!

Answer (score -1):

Array is Object in JavaScript, which is reference type.
So you can not use "===" to check whether two arrays are equals.

For example:

```
var array1=[1,2];
var array2=[1,2];

var result = array1 === array2;
```

the result will be false.

My suggestion is writing a new function to check whether two arrays are equals by comparing the items.

```
function areEquals(array1, array2){
   if(array1.length!==array2.length){
      return false;
   }
   for(var i in array1){
      if(array1[i]!==array2[i]){
         return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```